# Como passar matrizes por parâmetro em uma função em C?

Tags: c, matriz, parâmetros

Olá! Estou tendo problemas para passar matrizes como parâmetro em uma função que multiplica duas matrizes, das quais o usuário escolhe os índices de linha e coluna e as matrizes são geradas de forma aleatória, e, através de uma função, imprime na tela a matriz resultante da multiplicação das duas. Estou com problemas na passagem das matrizes e seus índices por parâmetro, na hora de chamar a função de multiplicar dentro da função main, o código até está compilando mas não exibe os resultados corretos. Alguém consegue me ajudar? Como eu posso fazer de uma forma simplificada ou de que maneira passar as variáveis na chamada da função de multiplicar matriz?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>


void main()
{
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, i, j;
    int mat1[20][20], mat2[20][20];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    
    printf("Você precisará digitar o índice das linhas e colunas de duas matrizes.\nLembre-se que o número de colunas da primeira deve ser igual ao número de colunas da segunda!\n\n");
    printf("Escolha a dimensão da primeira matriz!\n\n");
    do
    {
    //LER ÍNDICES DE LINHA E COLUNA DA MATRIZ 1
        printf("Digite o índice da linha: ");
        scanf("%d", &x1);
        printf("Digite agora o índice da coluna: ");
        scanf("%d", &y1);
        
    //COLOQUEI O LIMITE DOS ÍNDICES COMO 20 PARA A MATRIZ NÃO FICAR MUITO GRANDE
        if(x1 > 20 || y1 > 20)
        {
            printf("\nO índice da linha e da coluna deve ser menor ou igual a 20! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
        else if(x1 <= 1)
        {
            printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 linha! Digite novamente.\n\n");

        }
        else if(y1 <= 1)
        {
            printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 coluna! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
    }
    while(x1 > 20 || y1 > 20 || x1 <= 1 || y1 <= 1);
    
    //IGUALA O ÍNDICE DA MATRIZ 1 AOS ÍNDICES LIDOS PELO USUÁRIO
    mat1[20][20] = mat1[x1][y1];

    //FUNÇÃO PARA GERAR AS MATRIZES ALEATORIAMENTE
 srand(time(NULL));
    
    printf("\nA seguinte matriz foi gerada aleatoriamente:\n\n");
    
    //GERANDO A MATRIZ 1 ALEATORIAMENTE
    for(i = 0; i < x1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < y1; j++)
        {
            mat1[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            printf("%d ", mat1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
  printf("\nEscolha a dimensão da segunda matriz!\n\n");
    
    do
    {
    //LER ÍNDICES DE LINHA E COLUNA DA MATRIZ 2
        printf("Digite o índice da linha (deve ser igual ao nº de colunas da primeira): ");
        scanf("%d", &x2);
        printf("Digite agora o índice da coluna: ");
        scanf("%d", &y2);
        
    //LIMITE DE 20 PARA ÍNDICE DE LINHA E COLUNA
        if(x2 > 20 || y2 > 20)
        {
            printf("\nO índice da linha e da coluna deve ser menor ou igual a 20! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
        if(x2 <= 1)
        {
            printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 linha! Digite novamente.\n\n");

        }
        else if(y2 <= 1)
        {
            printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 coluna! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
        else if(y1 != x2)
        {
            printf("\nA linha da segunda deve ser igual a coluna da primeira! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
    }while(x2 > 20 || y2 > 20 || x2 <= 1 || y2 <= 1 || y1 != x2);
    
    //IGUALA O ÍNDICE DA MATRIZ 2 AOS ÍNDICES LIDOS PELO USUÁRIO
    mat2[20][20] = mat2[x2][y2];
    
    printf("\nA seguinte matriz foi gerada aleatoriamente:\n\n");
    
    //GERANDO A MATRIZ 2 ALEATORIAMENTE
    for(i = 0; i < x2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < y2; j++)
        {
            mat2[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            printf("%d ", mat2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nA matriz resultante da multiplicação das duas matrizes acima é:\n\n");
    
    //CHAMADA DA FUNÇÃO PARA MULTIPLICAR AS MATRIZES CRIADAS
    //***ACHO QUE O PROBLEMA É AQUI***
    
    multmat(mat1, mat2, x1, x2, y1, y2);
    system("pause");
}

    //CRIAÇÃO DA FUNÇÃO PARA MULTIPLICAÇÃO DAS MATRIZES
    //***ACHO QUE O PROBLEMA TAMBÉM É AQUI (NAS PASSAGENS DAS VARIÁVEIS POR PARÂMETRO)***
    
void multmat(int m1[][20], int m2[][20], int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    int i, j, k, aux;
    
    //CRIANDO A VARIÁVEL DE UMA MATRIZ PARA ARMAZENAR O RESULTADO DAS MULTIPLICAÇÕES
    int mr[20][20];
        
    //NÃO ENTENDI A LÓGICA DESSAS 3 ESTRUTURAS DE 'FOR' PARA MULTIPLICAÇÃO DAS MATRIZES
    //PEGUEI ESSA FUNÇÃO PRONTA NA INTERNET POIS NÃO SABIA COMO FAZER
    for(i = 0; i < x1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < y2; j++)
        {
            aux = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < y1; k++)
            {
                aux += ((m1[i][j])*(m2[i][j]));
            }
            mr[i][j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    //ESTRUTURA DE REPETIÇÃO PARA IMPRIMIR OS VALORES DA MATRIZ RESULTANTE DAS MULTIPLICAÇÕES
     for(i = 0; i < x1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < y2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", mr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, existem alguns problemas no seu código. Primeiro que vc nao importou a lib time.h ...   
Então la no inicio do código vc deve incluir `#include<time.h>`.

O seu problema de nao passar corretamente a matriz é porque la nos parâmetros da função você nao deve esperar receber a matriz dessa forma `int m1[][]`. ... você deve receber dessa forma `int** m1` ... pronto, isso resolve o seu problema.

O outro problema, é que você nao declarou a assinatura da função em um arquivo de cabeçalho nem no inicio do arquivo .c 
Então voce deve incluir isso la no seu arquivo de cabeçalho `void multmat(int** m1, int** m2, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);` ou no inicio do seu file .c

Enfim, depois dessa explicação bem superficial dos problemas, eu vou deixar aqui o código funcionando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

void multmat(int** m1, int** m2, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);

int main()
{
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, i, j;
    int mat1[20][20], mat2[20][20];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    
    printf("Você precisará digitar o índice das linhas e colunas de duas matrizes.\nLembre-se que o número de colunas da primeira deve ser igual ao número de colunas da segunda!\n\n");
    printf("Escolha a dimensão da primeira matriz!\n\n");
    do
    {
    //LER ÍNDICES DE LINHA E COLUNA DA MATRIZ 1
        printf("Digite o índice da linha: ");
        scanf("%d", &x1);
        printf("Digite agora o índice da coluna: ");
        scanf("%d", &y1);
        
    //COLOQUEI O LIMITE DOS ÍNDICES COMO 20 PARA A MATRIZ NÃO FICAR MUITO GRANDE
        if(x1 > 20 || y1 > 20)
        {
            printf("\nO índice da linha e da coluna deve ser menor ou igual a 20! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
        else if(x1 <= 1)
        {
            printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 linha! Digite novamente.\n\n");

        }
        else if(y1 <= 1)
        {
            printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 coluna! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
    }
    while(x1 > 20 || y1 > 20 || x1 <= 1 || y1 <= 1);
    
    //IGUALA O ÍNDICE DA MATRIZ 1 AOS ÍNDICES LIDOS PELO USUÁRIO
    mat1[20][20] = mat1[x1][y1];

    //FUNÇÃO PARA GERAR AS MATRIZES ALEATORIAMENTE
 srand(time(NULL));
    
    printf("\nA seguinte matriz foi gerada aleatoriamente:\n\n");
    
    //GERANDO A MATRIZ 1 ALEATORIAMENTE
    for(i = 0; i < x1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < y1; j++)
        {
            mat1[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            printf("%d ", mat1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
  printf("\nEscolha a dimensão da segunda matriz!\n\n");
    
    do
    {
    //LER ÍNDICES DE LINHA E COLUNA DA MATRIZ 2
        printf("Digite o índice da linha (deve ser igual ao nº de colunas da primeira): ");
        scanf("%d", &x2);
        printf("Digite agora o índice da coluna: ");
        scanf("%d", &y2);
        
    //LIMITE DE 20 PARA ÍNDICE DE LINHA E COLUNA
        if(x2 > 20 || y2 > 20)
        {
            printf("\nO índice da linha e da coluna deve ser menor ou igual a 20! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
        if(x2 <= 1)
        {
            printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 linha! Digite novamente.\n\n");

        }
        else if(y2 <= 1)
        {
            printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 coluna! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
        else if(y1 != x2)
        {
            printf("\nA linha da segunda deve ser igual a coluna da primeira! Digite novamente.\n\n");
        }
    }while(x2 > 20 || y2 > 20 || x2 <= 1 || y2 <= 1 || y1 != x2);
    
    //IGUALA O ÍNDICE DA MATRIZ 2 AOS ÍNDICES LIDOS PELO USUÁRIO
    mat2[20][20] = mat2[x2][y2];
    
    printf("\nA seguinte matriz foi gerada aleatoriamente:\n\n");
    
    //GERANDO A MATRIZ 2 ALEATORIAMENTE
    for(i = 0; i < x2; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < y2; j++)
        {
            mat2[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            printf("%d ", mat2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nA matriz resultante da multiplicação das duas matrizes acima é:\n\n");
    
    //CHAMADA DA FUNÇÃO PARA MULTIPLICAR AS MATRIZES CRIADAS
    //***ACHO QUE O PROBLEMA É AQUI***
    
    multmat(mat1, mat2, x1, x2, y1, y2);
    return 0;
}

    //CRIAÇÃO DA FUNÇÃO PARA MULTIPLICAÇÃO DAS MATRIZES
    //***ACHO QUE O PROBLEMA TAMBÉM É AQUI (NAS PASSAGENS DAS VARIÁVEIS POR PARÂMETRO)***
    
void multmat(int** m1, int** m2, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2)
{
    int i, j, k, aux;
    
    //CRIANDO A VARIÁVEL DE UMA MATRIZ PARA ARMAZENAR O RESULTADO DAS MULTIPLICAÇÕES
    int mr[20][20];
        
    //NÃO ENTENDI A LÓGICA DESSAS 3 ESTRUTURAS DE 'FOR' PARA MULTIPLICAÇÃO DAS MATRIZES
    //PEGUEI ESSA FUNÇÃO PRONTA NA INTERNET POIS NÃO SABIA COMO FAZER
    for(i = 0; i < x1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < y2; j++)
        {
            aux = 0;
            for(k = 0; k < y1; k++)
            {
                aux += ((m1[i][j])*(m2[i][j]));
            }
            mr[i][j] = aux;
        }
    }
    
    //ESTRUTURA DE REPETIÇÃO PARA IMPRIMIR OS VALORES DA MATRIZ RESULTANTE DAS MULTIPLICAÇÕES
     for(i = 0; i < x1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < y2; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", mr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Se voce é alguem que esta começando agora na área de programação, eu recomendo que nao copie o o código que mandei, mas estude os pontos dos quais eu mencionei acima sobre os erros que você cometeu. Esses erros são bem comuns em quem esta começando e você esta indo super bem. :)

Answer (score -1):

Gostaria de recomendar que revise o tópico de produto entre matrizes, em álgebra linear antes de reimplementar o código, será de muito proveito para entender alguns trechos.

Mesmo o código passado por nosso amigo Guilherme, não funciona corretamente para algumas matrizes. A causa, passar matrizes como parâmetros de funções, da maneira que foi passado.

A maneira correta de passar este tipo de parâmetro (matrizes), para uma função é via ponteiro. Contornei o problema dispensando o uso da função "multmat", implementando a diretamente na função main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

// void multmat(int* *m1, int* *m2, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);
// DISPENSO O USO DA FUNÇÃO ACIMA

int main()
{
   int x1, y1, x2, y2, i, j;
   int mat1[20][20], mat2[20][20];
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

   printf("Você precisará INFORMAR O NÚMERO DE linhas e colunas de duas matrizes.",
            "\nLembre-se que o número de colunas da primeira deve ser igual ao número de LINHAS da segunda!\n\n");
   printf("Escolha a dimensão da primeira matriz!\n\n");
   do
   {
   //LER ÍNDICES DE LINHA E COLUNA DA MATRIZ 1
   //-TEM CERTEZA QUE É MESMO OS INDICES QUE DESEJAR LER?
       printf("Digite o NUMERO DE linhas: ");
       scanf("%d", &x1);
       printf("Digite agora o NUMERO DE colunas: ");
       scanf("%d", &y1);

   //COLOQUEI O LIMITE DOS ÍNDICES COMO 20 PARA A MATRIZ NÃO FICAR MUITO GRANDE
       if(x1 > 20 || y1 > 20)
       {
           printf("\nO NUMERO DE linhas OU colunas deve ser menor ou igual a 20! Digite novamente.\n\n");
       }
       else if(x1 <= 1)
       {
           printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 linha! Digite novamente.\n\n");

       }
       else if(y1 <= 1)
       {
           printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 coluna! Digite novamente.\n\n");
       }
   }
   while(x1 > 20 || y1 > 20 || x1 <= 1 || y1 <= 1);

   //IGUALA O ÍNDICE DA MATRIZ 1 AOS ÍNDICES LIDOS PELO USUÁRIO
   //mat1[20][20] = mat1[x1][y1]; //QUAL SENTIDO DESSA INTRUÇÃO??

   //FUNÇÃO PARA GERAR AS MATRIZES ALEATORIAMENTE
            srand(time(NULL));

   printf("\nA seguinte matriz foi gerada aleatoriamente:\n\n");

   //GERANDO A MATRIZ 1 ALEATORIAMENTE - VOCE TAMBEM ESTÁ EXIBINDO!
   for(i = 0; i < x1; i++)
   {
       for(j = 0; j < y1; j++)
       {
           mat1[i][j] = rand() % 20;
           printf("%d ", mat1[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
 printf("\nEscolha a dimensão da segunda matriz!\n\n");

   do
   {
   //LER ÍNDICES DE LINHA E COLUNA DA MATRIZ 2
   //-NOVAMNTE PERGUNTO, TEM CERTEZA QUE É MESMO OS INDICES QUE DESEJAR LER?
       printf("Digite A QUANTIDADE DE LINHAS (deve ser igual ao nº de colunas da primeira): ");
       scanf("%d", &x2);
       printf("Digite agora A QUANTIDADE DE COLUNAS: ");
       scanf("%d", &y2);

   //LIMITE DE 20 PARA ÍNDICE DE LINHA E COLUNA
       if(x2 > 20 || y2 > 20)
       {
           printf("\nO NUMERO DE linhas OU colunas deve ser menor ou igual a 20! Digite novamente.\n\n");
       }
       if(x2 <= 1)
       {
           printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 linha! Digite novamente.\n\n");

       }
       else if(y2 <= 1)
       {
           printf("\nUma matriz deve conter mais de 1 coluna! Digite novamente.\n\n");
       }
       else if(y1 != x2)
       {
           printf("\nA linha da segunda deve ser igual a coluna da primeira! Digite novamente.\n\n");
       }
   }while(x2 > 20 || y2 > 20 || x2 <= 1 || y2 <= 1 || y1 != x2);

   //IGUALA O ÍNDICE DA MATRIZ 2 AOS ÍNDICES LIDOS PELO USUÁRIO
   //mat2[20][20] = mat2[x2][y2]; //QUAL SENTIDO DISSO MESMO????

   printf("\nA seguinte matriz foi gerada aleatoriamente:\n\n");

   //GERANDO A MATRIZ 2 ALEATORIAMENTE - VOCE TAMBEM ESTÁ EXIBINDO!
   for(i = 0; i < x2; i++)
   {
       for(j = 0; j < y2; j++)
       {
           mat2[i][j] = rand() % 20;
           printf("%d ", mat2[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\nA matriz resultante da multiplicação das duas matrizes acima é:\n\n");

            int mr[20][20];
            int k;
   for(i = 0; i < x1; i++) /*CONTROLA A LINHA DE MAT1*/
   {
       for(j = 0; j < y2; j++) /*CONTROLA A COLUNA DE MAT2*/
       {
                                            mr[i][j] = 0;
           for(k = 0; k < y1; k++)
           {
               mr[i][j] = mr[i][j] + ((mat1[i][k])*(mat2[k][j]));
           }
       }
   }
   //ESTRUTURA DE REPETIÇÃO PARA IMPRIMIR OS VALORES DA MATRIZ RESULTANTE DAS MULTIPLICAÇÕES
    for(i = 0; i < x1; i++)
   {
       for(j = 0; j < y2; j++)
       {
           printf("%d ", mr[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Fiz alguns comentários e também algumas perguntas no seu código, reflita sobre. Quando entender completamente seu código implemente o também via ponteiro, será um exercício muito valioso. No mais, você está indo muito bem, continue assim.